# Proper demolition hammer selection for stone wall and concrete steps

Tags: concrete, walls, demolition

I’m looking to replace a wall under my deck, and to remove an old set of concrete stairs under same. I’m currently researching the project, and hoping to do it this fall in cooler weather.

The stone wall is deteriorating, so removing it shouldn’t be too difficult, but the stairs look like a tougher job. They’re solid masses of concrete in a tight spot and I’m not sure if they contain any rebar. I do know they have been sitting there for 60+ years.

**Question:** What size/class of demo hammer would be a good choice, and how long do you think the job would take?
(*Still figuring out if I want to buy a hammer or rent.*)

[image: wall and stairs]
[image: stairs]

Comment: @jwh20 the deck stairs are, but when the deck was built in 1969, it was built over the stairs you see above the wall.

Comment: the wall looks like it could be disassembled with a crowbar ... you may be able to pull the stairs out with a winch ... a tow truck may be able to pull them

Comment: You may want to do some exploratory excavation between the wall and old stairs - it looks like it's filled with rubble, and that may well be what's filled in under the poured steps. My concrete front steps are about 4" of concrete over stacked bricks - if that's what you've got, it seems this would be reasonable to attack by hand.

Comment: That looks like a mono pour bummer it is right next to the compressor but a skill saw with a masonry blade would be my first shot on the stairs with mesh and or rebar the concrete holds onto the concrete once it is cut it comes out much easier.

Comment: Personally, I'd just go rent a jackhammer for the stairs. If there is time in the rental period you could use it on the wall as well but like others mentioned a chisel, crowbar, and sledgehammer would probably suffice.

Comment: Chipping hammer for the stone. Jackhammer for the stairs, after you **pull deck boards out of the way**. Or just chip the stone and put lattice to hide the old stairs.

Answer (score 0):

Holding a demo hammer sideways to break up those stairs sounds like *very* tiring work. The class of demo hammer I'd prefer is called 'skid steer loader with breaker attachment.' Or Toro Dingo with breaker. When the breaking is done you can put the bucket back on one of these machines to cart the debris away.

Breaker attachments can also be had for mini excavators. These might give you a little more reach to get those stairs under the wood deck, as compared to how far you can reach with a loader-mounted breaker.

I'd guess that with equipment like this you'd have the wall broken down in under an hour. From here there's no telling whether those stairs are a solid mass of concrete, or might have a void filled with straw, construction debris, soil, or ???. If it's solid concrete then it's probably most of a day's work with this medium-heavy equipment. You could use a hammer drill to make some exploratory holes and discover how solid the stairs might be.

[image: skid steer loader with breaker attachment]
[image: Toro Dingo with breaker]

Comment: you are right a skid steer would be easy if there was open access, I don’t know anyone that would use several yards or more of concrete for steps. The side walls are usually 2-4” thick with dirt / rock filling most of the void.

Comment: I had a neighbor a few years ago who poured steps solid.. it was an existing home and he had to replace a steel framed staircase. Between the short load fee charged for delivery of a small load of ready mix and the cost and effort of bringing in fill material, he decided it was most economical to pour it solid instead. Seems like the staircase climbed about 5 feet; it must have taken about 3 cu yards to fill. I agree though that's probably an exception!

Comment: This sounds more expensive by several orders of magnitude. What's the minimum rental price for a skid steer w/ this attachment where you live? A suitable hammer would be around $30 and provide a lot more control.

Comment: @TylerH It's about $300 for a day, so one order of magnitude more cost. But compare the time and physical effort as well -- I'd pay $300 extra in a heartbeat to spend literally a few minutes breaking apart that wall and a few hours on the stairs, compared with a few hours on the wall and a grueling day or more on the stairs with a demo hammer.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think a demo hammer would be the best tool. Yes it may take some hard work out of the wall but it may take much longer.

The wall would come out with a heavy hand chisel and A 2 or 3 lb hammer. possibly easier than a demo hammer 1 wack in the right spot parallel between the stones may be faster the sharp impact separates blocks fairly easily. I have done large walls 1 strike per slab. I think the 6” wide chisel I use for popping tiles would work there. Worth a try and much cheaper and faster if it works.

The edit took out information needed to be there
Are the stairs a mono pour?
It looks like it if so there will be wire possibly rebar. In this case I would use a masonry blade in my skill saw dice the sides then figure the steps they may pull out but I would cut the sides for manageability. And that 2 or 3 lb hammer may be handy there again with the limited space.

If you want a demo hammer I would suggest a Hilti mine cost well over a thousand $ ~20 years ago and it has been rebuilt 1x but still works great with years of abuse.
For a limited use demo hammer I would suggest a harbor freight it is much lighter than my Hilti pro but at just over 10% of the cost it is a throw away, I did a big jobs for the kids and needed a second one  Tried the One from harbor freight under 200 several years ago and although it was not as powerful as the Hilti it did a surprisingly good job and I have used it quite a few times since. To do that wall with a demo get a spade bit, it will help pop them apart.

Again cut the wall of the steps if a mono pour there will be wire or rebar or has been in every one I have poured or taken out.

Comment: Have you ever worked with a product named Dexpan? Seems like it could have some utility in a situation like this.

Comment: I have not used dexpan I have used the abrasive and diamond / carbide blades to cut Chanel’s in boulders and split with wedges. With concrete it might work if it is not reenforced I don’t think it would work well when there is wire/ rebar in the concrete.

Comment: After looking at the de pan product drilling 1”+ holes is a massive amount of work and looking at there demo slab there was only a couple pieces of rebar . Note the concrete is still hanging on the rebar a slab with welded wire probably would not work at all drilling concrete is as much work as cutting  but drilling doesn’t cut the wire where cutting will.